# Kotlin: Missing kotlin.jvm.internal.FunctionReferenceImpl raised for kaptDebugKotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I'm new to Android development, maybe this is something obvious that I'm missing. I have switched from i7 to Apple M1 and when I'm building the project, I get the error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

I have run it then with `./gradlew clean build` and it seems that this is the issue:
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void kotlin.jvm.internal.FunctionReferenceImpl`

Java installed via `brew install java` is:

```
openjdk version "15.0.1" 2020-10-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 15.0.1+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The same setup seems to work fine on MacBook Pro i7. I wonder if this has to do with Apple M1 CPU?

**build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.1"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.myApp.vpn.android"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ["libs"]
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module")
    }
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.11.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.11.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.0'
    implementation('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp') {
        version { strictly '3.12.12' }
    }
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha04'
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.nulab-inc:zxcvbn:1.3.1'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.5.0'

}
```

Any advise, please?

Comment: try using openJDK 8, or using the inbuilt version bundled with Android Studio

Comment: Can you guid me on the latter one? But how comes this works on the other machine with OpenJDK 15?

Comment: Different CPU architectures mean different builds - so it may be a bug in build for M1

Answer (score 4):

I have found the problem.

I noticed that I had updated the Gradle on the M1. So it must have been something with the libraries. So I reverted them and tried to upgrade them one by one.

This is causing it:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.11.0'
```

Even version `1.10.0` has this problem.

but 1.9.3 works perfectly fine.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.9.3'
```

Comment: It would be handy to confirm if the same issue occurs on the i7 x86 based mac to rule out any x86 / arm / rosetta issue.

Comment: Sure, I just tested it. The good news is that 1.11.0 also fails on i7 laptop.  So it is not related to M1 architecture. I'm very surprised that 1.10.0 is also affected. How comes the devs have not noticed this issue yet? I have to report this.